# Magento - Catalog price rules not working until product updated

Tags: magento, catalog, magento-rules

I'm experiencing some issues about Catalog price rules: whenever I create a price rule, this is not applied to selected products until each of these products isn't updated someway. Reindex all data from Index management has no effect; even in case of new products created after the price rule, I can't see the special price frontend if I don't edit the products.

Am I the only one who has such a problem? Any idea if it could be cache related, or it's because different tables are affected on product insert or product update?

I'm working on Magento 1.6.1 C.E.

Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I just didn't notice the 'apply rule' button. I actually don't understand its meaning, since you can also set a start and a finish date for any rule. Problem solved for this time btw

Comment: I had a similar issue and neglected to hit the "apply rule" button. However, a CUSTOMER was able to see the discount immediately and was able to place the order at the discounted price. But when I viewed the site through the customer interface, it was not displaying for me. And the discounted price did not display in the Admin interface when creating an order either. Be cautious about the "apply" - just because it's not working for you does not mean it's not working for others.

Answer (score 3):

Also may be you missed this make sure you clicked **APPLY RULES** Button

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please check:

1. Is the rule active?
2. Has the rule been applied?
3. Is the rule active on this day?
4. Does the rule you created actually include the targeted products?
5. Does your rule not applied because of priority?
   If all of above are working then your rule will be visible to front ent when once your cron will run and once page cache will be flushed

Answer (score 1):

The cheap way is to go to the rule and click on 'Save and apply rule' button everyday, which will work but is not ideal.
As a solution, you need to setup a cronjob which refreshes the rule on daily basis. You can do this by going to System->configuration->system->cron. Or if you can setup the crontab if you have access to the SSH.